# Terraform enable Microsoft Defender for SQL in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, security, terraform, azure-sql-database

I need to enable Microsoft Defender for SQL in Terraform for the resource SQL Database, but I can't find any documentation about this for Terraform

Comment: I am also looking for information about this and have not found anything useful :/  I was directed to azure_security_center and don't see how it directly correlates to the enable for all blade.  See here for the issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/14409

Comment: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/configure-azurerm-resource-group-to-support-turning-on-azure-defender/33305 - created a discussion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [threat_detection_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/sql_database#threat_detection_policy) block for that.

Comment: Yes, but I need this for azurem_mssql_database, because I used this parameter for mssql database and is not working